# Adding a wpf button created in background thread to Mainwindow

Tags: wpf, multithreading

Here's my scenario : I have a simple wpf window with a button. When the user clicks on the button, I want to create  another window (let's call it child window) and then create a wpf button on a background thread, add it to the child window and show the child window. Here's the code for this:

```
        Button backgroundButton = null;
        var manualResetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[1];
        var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
        manualResetEvents[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var t = new Thread(x =>
        {
            backgroundButton = new Button { Content = "Child Button" };
            childWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(()                   => childWindow.MainPanel.Children.Add(backgroundButton)));
            manualResetEvents[0].Set();
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualResetEvents);
        childWindow.ShowDialog();
```

When I call the ShowDialog(), I get this error "**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**". I know that this error is because the button added to the child window is created on a background thread and hence we get this error. Question is: How do I get past this error and still have my button to be created on the background thread

Comment: i doubt this would work anyway. the current Dispatcher is set on any DispatcherObject when created (Button is a DO). there is no way to change it afterwards (without using some fancy reflection stuff).
afaik you cannot add children to visuals that have a different dispatcher thread as rendering would lead to InvalidOperationExceptions while calling Measure or Arrange.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `Dispatcher` every time, when you want to access Parent's window from another thread. I see in action of your thread , you use `backgroundButton` . Because of that, you must do whatever with your button inside `Dispathcer.BeginIvoke` statement
[EDIT] 
Change Thread action to this

```
var t = new Thread(x =>
    {
        backgroundButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(()                   => backgroundButton = new Button { Content = "Child Button" }));
        childWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(()                   => childWindow.MainPanel.Children.Add(backgroundButton)));
        manualResetEvents[0].Set();
    });
```

I wrote this according to your code.I doesn't check you code, but hope its right.

Comment: Javidan..I am not quite following what you are saying..Can you elaborate or post the code. That would be great